# Why does my Twilio MessagingResponse not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio

The following Twilio code doesn't work. This is my webhook handler in an ASP.NET (Core) 6.0 app.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("webhook-url")]
public IActionResult PostTwilioMessageReceived([FromForm] TwilioMessageReceivedFormModel formModel)
{
    // logging code etc.

    var response = new Twilio.TwiML.MessagingResponse();
    response.AddText($"You sent '{formModel.Body}' but our systems are dumb and can't process this yet.");
    
    return new TwiMLResult(response);
}
```

There are no errors. I don't receive the message, and my delivery status webhook doesn't appear to be called.

The method above is called as I see it in my logs.

Note - There is no "to" address. I have adapted sample code from Twilio's documentation which also does nothing to either read the sender address or configure the response with a recipient or other correlation ID.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-and-receive-media-messages-whatsapp-csharp-aspnet#generate-twiml-in-your-application

---

I've modified my logging to make doubly sure my webhook is being called. It is. And in Twilio's log there's no acknowledgement of the reply my webhook attempts to produce.

To be clear, the code above is using Twilio's libraries.

Comment: "my delivery status webhook doesn't appear to be called" - what exactly do you mean by that? especially since "The method above is called"?

Comment: I have another webhook which Twilio calls whenever I send a message. This is not called (nothing in logs) which may confirm that Twilio is dropping or unable to handle my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TwiML output of your application would be:

```xml
<Response>You sent '...' but our systems are dumb and can't process this yet.</Response>
```

Unfortunately, that isn't valid TwiML, instead it should look like this:

```xml
<Response>
   <Message>You sent '...' but our systems are dumb and can't process this yet.</Message>
</Response>
```

This will respond with a message to the sender. To do this, use the `.Message` method instead of `.AddText`:

```cs
response.Message($"You sent '{formModel.Body}' but our systems are dumb and can't process this yet.");
```

Everything else looks fine in your code AFAIK.

---

Aside: If all you need to do is to respond to the current sender with a single message, you can also respond with plain text and the `text/plain` content type.

###### Edit by OP

I also changed the return line to:

```
return this.TwiML(response);
```

Which was the advice of Twilio support. I didn't try it my original way, but assumed that if there was some kind of magic that's pre-addressing the response, or correlating it in some way, then it might be in using the helper function on the base controller. Thanks.

Comment: `.TwiML(response)` is the same as `new TwiMLResult(response)` so it wouldn't make a difference, but we do like using the method more as it follows the MVC code style more closely. You can find the source code on GitHub: https://github.com/twilio-labs/twilio-aspnet

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what caused this without seeing an error or message log. You should be able to see something in the "Monitor" in the console (more details [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/debugging-tools)).

I've had similar issues in the past with Node.js and the problem was there that I forgot to set the content-type of the response to `text/xml`. But I'm not sure if this is required in your C# code.

Comment: Thanks, there's nothing there. It's as if I returned nothing. I don't expect to have to set a content-type since I'm using Twilio's library to create the `MessagingResponse` and return a `TwiMLResult`. I would expect this to just work, or log an error. In fact, I need to double check my own logs to ensure the hook really is being called.

Comment: None of the samples seem to prepare the response with a To address. I assume the Twilio library automagically reads this information from the request.

Comment: Yes, the "to" is optional and it's use the sender address if not specified otherwise.